# MSBuild pre-build event that is a dependency at compile time but not at runtime

Tags: .net, build, msbuild

I have two projects in a SLN solution:

- Project X: executable.
- Project Y: library.

Project Y doesn't really depend on X (I shouldn't add X to the References list of Y), what happens is that project X is an executable that will do some manipulation of Y.dll after it's built.

So how to code this in their MSBuild .csproj files? I guess I need:

- A Pre-build task in project Y to build project X.
- A Post-build task in project Y to execute project X.

How to do this in MSBuild?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you add a reference to y to the solution that builds x and right click on the property for y and change the default action from do not copy to copy always, when the solution is built you just need a post-build event to run x, y will be in the same bin directory.

Comment: solution that builds X? I guess you mean "project" that builds X?

Comment: only thing is I would like Y.dll to stay in the place where is meant to be, that is src/Y/bin/Debug/Y.dll, then later call X.exe ../../../Y/bin/Debug/Y.dll

Comment: No, I mean visual studio solution ( which can contain multiple projects. If both x and y are in known locations relative to each other x can use a relative path to get to y.dll